# how can i get response time of a particular query using jdbc logging in weblogic?

Tags: logging, jdbc, weblogic

Can the response time of the particular query be logged in "Weblogic-jdbc logging" using configurarional changes to "oracleJdbcLogConfig.properties"?? or to get it, is there any other way available? i JUST want to know how much time does it take for my application running on weblogic to get a response of "a particular query/sometimes queries" run by application ...

Currently i have set everything well in my oracleJdbcLogConfig.properties file as follows:

```
    .level=SEVERE
    oracle.level=FINE
    oracle.jdbc.level=FINE
    oracle.jdbc.driver.level=FINE
    oracle.jdbc.pool.level=OFF
    oracle.jdbc.rowset.level=OFF
    oracle.jdbc.util.level=OFF
    oracle.jdbc.xa.level=FINE
    oracle.sql.level=FINE

    oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
    oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=D:/jdbclogs/jdbcLogging.log
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`
```

Using above configuration i am able to get the query, in "jdbcLogging.log" file but cant get how much time does it take to get response of that query. ( query being generated by my application )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this profiler :

http://www.slf4j.org/extensions.html

It is an extension from sl4j

Comment: Thanks for help Cris. Sorry for being late here as i was terribly caught in some important work. Let me check this out..